# How do I place an image/logo in browser tab

Tags: image, web, browser, tabs

Quick question. You know when you open a new window & at the top of the page you see the tab for said window & you'll see whatever you typed in your title tag & you'll see a little image (website's logo). How do I place an image/logo in that little tab? Do I have to place an image link within my title tag or something?!

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Round Table</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="RTH.css">
<script src="RTH.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<H1> Come & take a seat at the Round Table B] </H1> 

<p> "Where <i>REAL MUSIC</i> still exists"</p><br><br>

<ol type=I> <H2> <li>BEAT$</li> 
<br><li>Music by Mercile$$</li> 
<br><li>Spoken Word</li> <br>
<li><a href="RthPg2.html" title="RthPg2">Tale$ of a Blind Sword$man</a></li> </H2> </ol><br><br><br>

<dt><i>RTH</i> consists of:</dt> 
<dd>Show Luciano, Pistol McFly, Dior, YZ, & last but not least...Mercile$$</dd>

<p> thee music industry is DEAD !! i hope to bring restoration.<br>

                                                                                            ~mercile$$</p><br>

<footer>&copy; Round Table</footer>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

& here's my CSS file:

```
body {
        background-image: url("Round Table, Hoe II.jpg");
    background-repeat: Repeat;
    font-family: AR Christy, Kozuka Gothic Pr6N, Cooper std;
    color: Red;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #CEA40C, 0 -1px 0 #CEA40C, 0 1px 0 #CEA40C, -1px 0 0 #CEA40C;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 700px;

}

h1 {
    font-family: AR Christy, Kozuka Gothic Pr6N, Cooper std;
    color: Red;
    text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #CEA40C, 0 0px 0 #CEA40C, 0 2px 0 #CEA40C, 0px 0 0 #CEA40C;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    width: 700px;

}

i {
    font-family: AR Christy, Kozuka Gothic Pr6N, Cooper std;
    color: White;
    text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #CEA40C, 0 0px 0 #CEA40C, 0 2px 0 #CEA40C, 0px 0 0 #CEA40C;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    width: 700px;

}

dt {

    color: #1BD29B;
    text-shadow: 4px 0 0 #CEA40C, 0 0px 0 #CEA40C, 0 4px 0 #CEA40C, 0px 0 0 #CEA40C;
    font-size: 45pt;
    padding: 10px;


}

dd {

    color: White;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; 
    background: #f03; 
    border: solid 2px #fff;

}

p {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; 
    background: #f03; 
    border: solid 2px #fff; 

}

footer {



}
```

Answer (score 14):

its easy use this site to convert the image http://www.favicongenerator.com/
and then in the head, but change the name of ur image and path

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/logo-favicon.ico.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a square image or icon then put this code in your head

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/path/image.png"/>
```

Comment: The image size can be 24 px also. This way works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing is to put your link between the head tags:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/logo.ico">
    </head>
    .
    .
    .
</html>
```